# How to tell the time a message read with imap()

Tags: time, imap

I'd like to know if it is possible to tell when the message is read. I mean when the msg is flagged as not unseen (it is read). The Unread status must be ''. Is there any timestamp included with this flag?

Comment: Wasn't this something Microsoft Exchange tried to implement way back when that could easily be circumnavigated by simply using another email client?

Comment: I don't understand, is it possible or not?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think so.

Comment: Umm... The thing is I have to run the imap with custom requirements which the market email clients doesn't existed. For example, there're 10 accounts and a boos needs to know how are those guys react to the incoming email, read it, reply it or delete it by the number of msg, time of read etc...

Comment: IMAP Flags do not have time stamps.

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible. There is no timestamp.

There is, however, something that may help you. I don't know what your goal is here, but perhaps the [modseq](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4551) helps. Every time the message changes (ie. a flag changes), the modseq increases.

In most cases, this means that while you cannot see when the \seen flag was set, you can sort the messages by flag change time, and since almost all flag changes occur at read time that means you can sort by something very like read time.

Comment: CONDSTORE is not supported by all servers.